# adduplex ad is black rectangle when user offline

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have ads in my app. If user is offline place where is an ad is a black rectangle. Can I change it to transparent or put something else like text or image ? Because this black place is very ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hide the `AdControl` on Errors. Remember to show the `AdControl` again when the new ad has been loaded:

```
<adduplex:AdControl
    AdLoaded="ShowAd"
    AdLoadingError="HideAd"
    ...
```

code behind:

```
private void ShowAd(object sender, AdLoadedEventArgs e)
{
    AdDuplexAd.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
}

private void HideAd(object sender, AdLoadingErrorEventArgs e)
{
    AdDuplexAd.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```